# Compliance test mode in Gen1/2 and Gen3

Tags: high-speed, pcie

I'm looking the mindshare book for TX compliance test.
Somehow I'm confused about the method to enter the Polling.Compliance substate.
In Gen1/2, it seems that of the transmitter detects a 50 Ohm load, it'll enter the compliance substate.
However, in Gen3, I can't find such condition.
Can anyone help me on this?
Thanks.

Comment: Detecting a 50 ohm load (on each diff pin) is part of the detect state machine. That starts the LTSSM training sequence for all versions of PCI express (otherwise it would not be backwardly compatible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Detect state machine (in detect.detect) looks for a valid link partner electrically by (effectively) measuring the load impedance on a transmitter port.

If this is successful, the state machine will enter the polling state machine where it will start transmitting (and hopefully receiving) TS1 and TS2 ordered sets. This is true for all versions of PCI express.

The details of Gen 3 (different speed capabilities, different line coding) are done later in the sequence.